# Tools for Testing and Debugging in .NET (VS2010)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am using VS2010 and to that I am also using WCF. Now for testing and Debugging purpose, what are the tools available online for free or paid?

Please share your experience too. Thank you :)

Comment: As an open discussion around unit testing and debugging in visual studio this probably would have been better suited as a community wiki post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you use visual studio express that will allow you to debug.  It sounds like you are just using the compiler.  This puts a nice IDE, although stripped down for you to use, and is much cheaper than full visual studio.

My experience is visual studio is a great IDE and I'd be loathe to go to a 3rd party.

The links below are visual basic and visual studio.

However if your question did mean what to use in visual studio then please check out the links on msdn, as they are very thorough.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Basic

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS